# Element changes width (?) after hover

Tags: html, css, nav

So I making a menu for a website, whenever the website loads the menu looks like img#1, the icons on the side are stacked, which I don't want to. 
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4JJR.jpg)
After you hover over the icons they stack properly img#2.
[after hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axjFj.jpg)
Which is how I actually want it.
I am sure it's just something small but I can't figure it out?

```
nav {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2% 0;
}

.menu-icon {
    display: none;
}
.main-nav {
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-left:4%;
    width:fit-content;
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right:5%;
}

nav a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--light-color);
    font-family: var(--font-h);
}
.icon-nav{
    margin-left:auto;
    padding-right:4%;
}
.icon-nav a{
    padding: 0 5%;
}
```

html

```
<nav>
    <div class="menu-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
        <div class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/#about-me">About me</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/#skills">Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/#contact-wrapper">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-nav">
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You will need to post the relevant HTML and CSS so we can see what is going on.

Comment: @maria Haave you tried anything? If yes, please show your code!

Comment: Sorry, first comment and accidentally hit enter which posted the question. Code added

Comment: I think your example photos are the same picture.

Comment: I'd advise against using percentages for `margin` and `padding`

Comment: Could you include the html objects in question? Also you said it fixes itself on hover. Is there any other css sheets(or APIs for display) that you might be using?

Comment: @merlin I am using font awesome and google fonts.

Comment: @mattCoady thanks , you were right, its fixed now. I hope everything thats needed is included

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely related to a problem in your layout of `.icon-nav` and it's padding.
[image: problem]
Some ways you can fix this is by:

Adding `:not(:last-child)` in the `.icon-nav a` CSS selector making it:

```
.icon-nav a:not(:last-child) {
    padding: 0 5%;
}
```

---

**OR**

Adding:

- First, adding `width: 15%;` to `.icon-nav`.
- Second, sdding `width: 75%;` to `.main-nav`.
- and adding a

  ```
  .icon-nav::before {
      content: "";
      width: 15%;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  ```

```css
/******* EXTRA *******/
#screen{
 resize:horizontal;
 overflow:hidden;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" ><rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="lightgrey"/><rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="lightgrey"/></svg>');
}
/*********************/
/********** Things forgotten **********/
html {
  --main-bg-color: black;
  --light-color: red;
  --font-h: /*monospace*/
  ;
}
ul {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#screen div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
}
#screen div * {
  border-width: 0;
}
/**************************************/

nav {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2% 0;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}
.main-nav {
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 4%;
  width: fit-content;
  /* ADDED { */  width: 70%;  /* } */
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
nav a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--light-color);
  font-family: var(--font-h);
}
/*= ADDED =======================*/
    .icon-nav::before {
      content: "";
      width: 15%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
/*===============================*/
.icon-nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 4%;
  /* ADDED {*/  width: 15%;  /* } */
}
.icon-nav a {
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="screen">
    <nav>
      <div class="menu-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/#about-me">About me</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/#skills">Skills</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/#contact-wrapper">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-nav">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true">&#61595;</i>
        </a>
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true">&#61593;</i>
        </a>
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true">&#61665;</i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```